# Fast and efficient way of creating regular snapshots of a huge folder in Windows

Tags: windows, backup, windows-8.1

Over the years, I've built up a large collection of files that I store under a single directory tree. This single directory tree contains all the digital files I care about that aren't handled by some online service.

I'm already backing this folder up with SkyDrive, but that only protects me in the case of catastrophic failure. Since SkyDrive automatically mirrors changes I make on my computer to the cloud, it won't help if I accidently delete something, or if an important file gets corrupted, etc.

For this reason, I want to start creating regular snapshots of my directory that I can go back to in case I need to retrieve an old version of a file, or restore my entire directory to some prior state. I know that I could just have a program regularly clone the whole directory to a timestamped folder, but that would be very inefficient since the directory is huge and only a small percentage of the files in there actually change from month to month. What should I do?

Comment: Windows has the capability to keep history of files within a copy `Shadow Copy` is the current name of that feature.  I also use Acronis True Image ( there are other choices ) to keep an incremental backup of specfic folders I care about.  I believe `Carbonite` keeps file history within a folder that is marked to be backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring to Dropbox instead of SkyDrive would be the simplest solution as it keeps past file versions.

Comment: Maybe, but I have 25 GB free on SkyDrive and only 2.75 GB on Dropbox.